# Wrong content type text/xml

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, jax-ws, exchangewebservices

i am working on my webservice now (i use jax ws, jboss application server version 4.0.4, EJB for implementation of web service), when i started testing of my web service with guys who are going to use it, all was ok for me but in their software was error

`{"The content type text/xml;charset=UTF-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly}`.

For me it looks like my web service use soap 1.1 instead of soap 1.2, is it possible to set up it through the jax ws annotation on my class? I found `@BindingType` annotation and tried use `@BindingType(SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING)` in my EJB class, but wsdl still the same as before and content type was not changed. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is an issue about the SOAP version.

Exchange Server is extremely picky about the charset specification. It has to be `charset=utf-8`, lowercase and without quotes. I had to overwrite the default `charset="utf-8"` that my SOAP code added to the SOAP calls.

I can't help you how to do this override in Java, because I'm working in Delphi. Maybe another reader can edit my answer and replace this last paragraph with the proper instructions to do so in Java.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, we've already found the reason for issue and fixed it

Comment: If you think that reason is valuable for other people, please write an answer to your own question here. You can mark that as the correct answer after 2 days.